# Regex to find sql comments

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex which can be used to match SQL style comments. Single line comments was fairly easy --.* however I can't work out how to match multi line comments. I don't need the actual replacement code just the regex to match the comments.

For instance:

```
select * from valid_sql1;

select * from valid_sql2; --comment here

--comment select * from this_is_still_a_comment;

 /*
 select * from this_is_not_valid;
 */

 /*comment*/ select * from valid_sql3; /*this is a comment*/
```

Should become:

```
 select * from valid_sql1;

 select * from valid_sql2;

 select * from valid_sql3;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Qix the robo-approvers and the random editors are out in full force tonight. Good rollback.

Comment: Why would anyone want to find comments in SQL, if not for removing those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `g`lobal modifier if your Regex engine accepts:

```
/\/\*.*?\*\/|--.*?\n/gs
```

`s` modifier is needed for multi-line comments matching.

### [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fJ1nZ9)

Comment: Thanks, demo was very helpful, modified slightly to work in java replaceAll \\/\\*[\\s\\S]*?\\*\\/

Comment: Nice. One warning though: it doesn't match a comment at end of file with no linebreak, so it's worth appending a linebreak to the script first to avoid having to treat EOF any differently.  

To use this in .Net, the syntax I ended up with is:  

    `string scriptWithoutComments = Regex.Replace(script + "\n", @"\/\*.*?\*\/|--.*?\n", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

Comment: It will match comment-like blocks that are inside text.

Answer (score 1):

### Regular Expression:

`(?s)/\*.*?\*/|--comment[^\r\n]*`

### Replacement Text:

Empty space.

---

That will remove the comments for you. You will have to match the entire file, not line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

How to ignore the comment in SQL string.

```
--comment1

select *  from /*my table*/sample where a = 's -- string'
and c = 'ss/**/ /* */ 
 /*123*/'

/*
*
*/

/*  */

/**/
```