# How to do a sql query with "-- a comment" in the code?

Tags: sql, node.js

When I do this

```
connexion.query(the_sql_file);
```

I have this error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '; -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
```

because apparently, I have a very long .sql file with comments inside.
There are a lot of comments marked with "-- comment"

Question: How to query this, with "--" comments, without throwing exceptions?

Comment: Did you try removing the comments and then executing the same query ?

Comment: No i can't because the .sql file that i must use has 2000 lines of code

Comment: I think Alon meant to give it a go to see if that is in fact what causes the error.

Comment: Remove the comments with Regex. Find them as shown here in [Regex to find sql comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017075/regex-to-find-sql-comments) and remove them. Then execute the query to see if it works.

Comment: You say it's 2000 lines, but how many comments are there?

Answer (score 0):

Try export file with this  **mysqldump -u root -p  databasebame > database.sql --compact**

In this "--comments" parts is not included.

and you can refer the link [How can I get rid of these comments in a MySQL dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916392/how-can-i-get-rid-of-these-comments-in-a-mysql-dump)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pg-minify](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-minify) to remove all comments, and minify the SQL at the same time.